# Invalid operands of types 'double' and 'const char [13]' to binary 'operator!='

Tags: c++

I'm using double (float) variables for an algorithm, but it gives me this error:

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'double' and 'const char [9]' to binary 'operator!='

Which operator should I use, then?

```
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     double a, b, Spa, Tim, Acc, Vel1, Vel2, Velocity, Space, Acceleration;
     cout << "Hello. This program may calculate velocity, space, time and acceleration.\n" << endl;
     cout << "Please, insert what you want to calculate.\n" << endl;
     cin >> a;
     do
     {
         cout << "Incorrect value.\n" << endl;
         cout << "Please, insert what you want to calculate.\n" << endl;
         cin >> a;
     }
     while (a != "Velocity" | a != "Acceleration");
     if (a == Velocity);
     {
         cout << "With space or acceleration value?\n" << endl;
         cin >> b;
         if (b == Space);
        {
            cout << "Insert space and time values.\n" << endl;
            cin >> Spa >> Tim;
            Vel1 = Spa / Tim;
            cout << "The velocity is " << Vel1 << " km/h.\n" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (b == Acceleration);
            {
                cout << "Insert acceleration and time values.\n" << endl;
                cin >> Acc >> Tim;
                Vel2 = Acc / Tim;
                cout << "The velocity is " << Vel2 << " km/h.\n" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a double with a string?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth,  was going to say the same thing.  A double is a numerical data type.

Comment: It's meaningless to perform a comparison between numeric data and english text, so you really can't use any operator.    Please could you step back a little and describe the actual problem are you trying to solve?    i.e. what are you actually trying to check for in the algorithm?

Comment: @BenCottrell I've added another piece of algorithm. My scope is to insert what I want to calculate (i.e. Velocity or Acceleration), and do different calculations based on what you have inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Plain Old Data" (POD) types in C++, such as `double`, `int`, `char`, etc. do not carry any semantic information about the thing they represent; or to put that another way, a number is *just* a number.

If you want to carry some kind of semantic meaning along with your number - for example, you want a number which represents something 'real' (temperature, speed, direction, CPU cycles, etc.), then you'll need to store that in a different kind of variable (a `std::string` would work for your program)

i.e.

```
std::string a, b;
double Spa, Tim, Acc, Vel1, Vel2, Velocity, Space, Acceleration;
```

You'll need to make sure you're always comparing `a` and `b` to strings:

```
if (a == "Velocity")
{
```

and..

```
    cout << "With space or acceleration value?\n" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    if (b == "Space")
    {
```

Also, be careful about not putting semicolons `;` at the end of `if ()` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, please don't name your variables `a` and `b`. Coming from physics, where _a_ stands for acceleration, something like `if(a == "Velocity")` stops my reading flow and makes me think about the line. `typeOfQuantity` or `variableToInput` would be better.

Comment: And one more tip, consider converting the input to lower case first. The text above the input suggests I can type "velocity" or "acceleration", but you only check if I entered "Velocity" or "Acceleration".

Comment: @CompuChip I don't disagree, however in the spirit of trying to keep the answer as close to the question as possible, this answer re-uses the same variable names `a` and `b` as per the original question, as well as `"Velocity"` and `"Acceleration"` string literals in the comparison.    But those are good suggestions for code review / improvement on the code in the question.